# How to simulate a hub in Virtualbox?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I have the following network topology simulated using VirtualBox:

```
Ubuntu1 >> IPFire1 ---- IPFire2 << Ubuntu2
```

All this network links are internal networks. Of course, IPFire 1 and IPFire 2 are on the same internal network, IPFire is a firewall distribution, I use it to make an IPsec VPN. For the purpose of packet sniffing I thought of connecting IPFire 1 and 2 through a hub, this hub will be connected also to the sniffer VM. I have been told to create a third VM with two network interfaces, one connected to IPFire 1 on an internal network, the other interface is connected to IPFire 2 on another internal network. Promiscuous mode must be set to "All VMs" for both interfaces. The problem with this network topology is that IPFire 1 and 2 are not on the same network, as such, I will not be able to establish the VPN. How to establish this hub correctly?

Comment: Just curious ... what is the intention of this setup? If IPFire1 and IPFire2 are on the same subnet, wouldn't it be easier and more realistic to scap 1 firewall and connect Ubuntu1 and 2 to different interfaces on it? If you're trying to simulate 2 different locations that need an IPSec tunnel, you will need to work with a 3rd firewall/router (which would act as the internet gateway between the 2 firewalls).

Comment: IPFire is a linux firewall distribution, It divides the network into four segments, I am only using two of them: the green (trusted and to be protected network) and the red (the untrusted external network). In a private network where I don't have public IP, so I use private IPs, if I put the red interface of IPFire 1 and 2 in different subnets, they will not be on the same network, and thus no VPN or any type of connection can be established between them. The two firewalls are in fact the Internet gateways for their respective networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create your sniffer VM with a single NIC connected to the same internal network `IPFire1` and `IPFire2`.  Just make sure the promiscuous mode is set to "Allow All" and you should be able to pickup all the traffic.

See:

- [[vbox-dev] How should "promiscuous mode" work ?](https://www.virtualbox.org/pipermail/vbox-dev/2011-May/009635.html)
- [Promiscuous Mode - Allow VMs vs Allow All?](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=44258)

Comment: Yes, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use bridged networking and you separate the networks by subnetting. For example:

- Ubuntu1: 192.168.100.x/24 (LAN)
- IPFire1: 192.168.110.x/24 (WAN) / 192.168.100.x/24 (LAN)
- IPFire2: 192.168.120.x/24 (WAN) / 192.168.200.x/24 (LAN)
- Ubuntu2: 192.168.200.x/24 (LAN)
- IPFire3: 192.168.110.x/24 (LAN1) / 192.168.120.x/24 (LAN2) and if you want a WAN as well.

If you want to physically separate the networks as well, you have the option of using host-only and NAT for the different subnets, or a combination thereof. You will have to use separate subnets in any case, meaning you can't use 192.168.100.x/24 for your Ubuntu1 and 2. In a real-life environment you could do this if the networks were separated by the internet, but your host needs to be able to talk to both on separate networks. If you'd use the same subnet, you'd cause trouble.

With regards to your sniffer, if you connect it to either port of IPFire3, you'd see all promiscuous traffic going back and forth between IPFire1 and IPFire2.

Comment: Do you suggest using bridged networking for all network segments in topology, or just the IPFire1 IPFire 2 link? Also, you are having IPFire 1 and 2 in different networks, they must be in the same network to connect them together.

Comment: You CAN use bridged networking for everything, but it's not a must. And no, IPFire1 and 2 don't need to be on the same network. Your IPSec will create that network tunnel. It's the same principle how companies connect different locations together over the internet, using IPSec. Consider your IPFire3 to be the "Internet", or your ISP's firewall/gateway in this scenario.

Comment: Ok, I will try to configure the network the way you described. For IPFire 3, you mean that I should put IPs in the same subnet of IPFire 1 and 2 respectively, right?

Comment: I have IPFire1 and IPFire2 bridged on eth0, both interface of IPFire 3 are bridged on eth0 as well, IPs, gateways and mask are assigned manually on IPFire 3. I can ping from it to IPFire 1 and 2. Put IPFire 1 can't ping to IPFire 2?!

Comment: I have no knowledge of the IPFire firewall, so I can't help you there. You will have to configure the firewall so that traffic is routed from 1 interface to another, and obviously you have to open the firewall to allow the traffic you want to send over the connection. It's similar to your Ubuntu1--IPFire1____IPFire2--Ubuntu2 setup. For Ubuntu1 to reach Ubuntu2, both IPFire firewalls need some configuration.